# Using a unique name infront of controller MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes

I am in need to create a company_number name before the controller, I have the following code already that does this for me

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{company_number}/{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index"}
    );
```

The unique name will besomething like
/company_number/home/ or /company/home/index

When the person login I must be able to retrieve company_number and then get the correct database for the person to work in.

How can I get this company_number using an attribute and set this value then to a Session["DatabaseName"] so if I have a controller. (company_number is not the database name, merely a key that I will use to get the database name)

```
[CompanyAttribute]
public class MyController {}
```

What I want to achieve:

I have one system with multiple companies using the system, so what I want to do is, if a user from CompanyA use the system and logs in the system must automatically know (wel learn from the code) what database to use for the Session.

Eg
I share the following link to companyA. http://www.myawesomesystem.co.za/company_a_uniquenumber/home/login or index
Then from that I want to get company_a_uniquenumber before `Login` action is reached and using a query to another database get the database linked to the company_a_uniquenumber.

Comment: Probably you can use `HttpRequestBase.RawUrl`, `Request.Url.PathAndQuery` or `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` to capture company number part and use `String.Split('/')` to separate between URL sections.

Comment: That depends on *where* you are instantiating the database connection. If you use an `ActionFilter` you cannot rely on dependency injection for the DB inside your controller (they are executed after the controller is created). Give us more information about what you are trying to do and maybe we can help you better.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma updating my question

Comment: Is [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602460/multi-database-for-multi-tenant-with-code-first-ef-6-and-asp-net-mvc-4) helpful?

Comment: Im going to give that a try, but that is exactly what I want to achieve